# Cannot get full-width li's inline

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a slider effect with a list of images. I need each one to by inline and take up with full screen width. I'm using float and also tried making the li's inline. The only thing that gets them on the same line is when they're not full width. How do I accomplish this while also having each li full-width of the screen? So they should extend past screen width.

Here is a screen shot of the current behavior:
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4177243/f8d1a38ce4b6096344f7f7befd4176fe

```
.mobile-slider-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
.mobile-slider-wrapper ul {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}
.mobile-slider-wrapper li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: When you say you want them all inline, but 100% width, are you trying to have them overflow the page and be scroll-able? Or do some sort of animation with them? stacking them all on top of each other is easy, but probably not your desired result.

Comment: @DBS what I'm trying to do is create a slider effect. So yes overflow the page but remain hidden until they "slide" into view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of the `vw` unit and a non-wrapping container to achieve this effect.

Here's a CSS mock up:

```css
#container { 
  /* This stops the items wrapping over onto the next line */
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  /* We set the width and scroll to stop this container affecting the entire page's width */
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100vw;
  
  /* This prevents any gaps between inline elements, keep in mind that if your child elements contain text, they will need to reset the font size, or this property can be removed */
  font-size: 0;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100vw; /* Make the item take up the full windows width*/
  height: 100px;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: #F00;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: #0F0;
}

.item3 {
  background-color: #00F;
}

.item4 {
  background-color: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item item1"></div>
  <div class="item item2"></div>
  <div class="item item3"></div>
  <div class="item item4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to use some JS to calculate the width on the wrapper.  2 slides = 200vw's, 3 slides = 300vw's, and so on.

```
$('.mobile-slider-wrapper').css('width', ($('.mobile-slider-wrapper').children().length * 100) + 'vw');
```

Comment: The `vw` and `vh` units are percentages of the screen's width and height. You'd need `100vw` to fill the whole screens width.

Comment: I haven't had my coffee. Fixed.